# Consulta relacionada a la palabra reservada like

Tags: sql

Quiero saber que puedo utilizar envés de like en una query si la columna es de tipo smallint.

En una tabla tengo dos columnas... descripcion de tipo varchar y código que es de tipo smallint; donde quiero consultar todos los items que contengan un número.

```
tabla productos
descripcion | codigo
carne         1
pescado       2
leche         10
harina        11
```

la query sería:

```
select * from productos where codigo "like" 1
```

y me devolvería

```
carne         1
leche         10
harina        11
```

solo que like ni contains funciona con el tipo de dato.

utilizo CatalinaDB

Comment: ¿Podrías dar un ejemplo de lo que buscas?

Comment: Podrias ser mas especifico por favor dejas la pregunta abierta, que haz intentado, tu tabla etc podria ayudar

Comment: Hola bienvenido por favor lee [ask], no queda claro lo que buscas resolver, puedes colocar la consulta que has tratado así como el resultado esperado? Gracias

Comment: Nos aclaras sql para que base de datos? la respuesta puede llegar a ser diferente segun la base que uses

Comment: Si usas sql Server puedes castear el dato asi 
SELECT * FROM productos WHERE CAST(codigo as VARCHAR(25)) LIKE '%1%'

Comment: No quedaría con `LIKE "1%"` colocando a `%` al final para indicar que te encuentre todos los códigos que inician con 1?

Comment: @EdgarVazquez puso que la base es catalina.. antes de contestar, siempre preguntemos ;)

Comment: @Aprendiz otro.. y si mejor preguntamos si quiere los 1 en cualquier lado o solo adelante o solo atras?

Comment: @gbianchi ok ok tranquilo, por eso lo coloque como comentario no hay necesidad de enojarnos :D

Comment: :o Como no habia puesto la base de datos puse un ejemplo pero si ya vi.

Comment: @Aprendiz grrrrr (sale con un martillo) jajaja.. lo se.. lo se...

Comment: o sea.. la respuesta es lo que puso edgar, pero esa DB no la conozco para nada..

Comment: Santiago podrias decirnos que DB es esa, y donde esta la documentacion de la misma?

Answer (score 0):

creo que la forma más fácil de conseguir lo que quieres sería utilizando `regexp`.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM dual
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ('asdasd', '^[0-9]+$')
```

Nos devolverá un FALSE, ya que en la cadena no hay ningún caracter númerico.

Puedes utilizar estas referencias:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm

https://elbauldelcodigo.com/validar-solo-numeros-en-oracle/27/0